# Set up .gitignore file for .NET project

Tags: git, github, gitignore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSQwJ.png)
Can you please tell me how to set .gitignore in such a way that only the project and source code files remain when committing a .NET project?

I just try set up my .gitignore)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use https://gitignore.io

And will end up with something looking like that:
https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/visualstudio,csharp,dotnetcore,aspnetcore

Other solution:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore